# Display content between set products on magento 2 category page

Tags: magento2, category, collection, static-content

I was wondering if there would be a solution to display blocks, with content i can enter in the backend, between or after a set amount of products. I know i can display some static content at the top of the page, but my client wants it to be between his products.

Any help or tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share some screenshot where you want to display that block

Comment: basically it should be able to display a block between every two products, so that the client can decide himself after how many products he wants to display a certain content block